# How do I add custom menu items to the office-button in office-2007?

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-2007

How do I add custom menu items to the office-button in office-2007?

In office 2007, I've managed to add some custom menu items to the office button, see the image below:
[image]
As you can see I added a 'label' and a 'button'.
Though this button lacks some things I would like to see.

What I would like to do is create a button like the 'Word Document' button seen in the picture below. A button with a form of heading and a description underneath it.
[image]

I've tried several things, and tried almost every option there was in the 'Ribbon.xml'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
<ribbon>
<officeMenu>
  <menu id="test" label="My Menu">
    <button id="id001" description="desc" enabled="true" label="label" screentip="screentip" supertip="supertip" tag="tag"/>
    <button id="id002" imageMso="AdpPrimaryKey" label="A button" description="desc" onAction="action" visible="true"  />
  </menu>
</officeMenu>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can find some informatie through the ribboneditor on the following site: http://www.andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor.htm

With the OfficeMenu example you get the following xml:

```
 <!--RibbonX Visual Designer 1.9 for Microsoft Word 12.0. XML Code produced on 2010/02/02-->
<customUI  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" >
    <ribbon >
        <officeMenu >
            <splitButton  id="Splitbutton1" >
                <button 
                    id="Button1"
                    imageMso="AdpPrimaryKey"
                    label="Company Lockers"/>
                <menu 
                    id="Menu1"
                    itemSize="large"
                    label="Menu1">
                    <menuSeparator 
                        id="Menuseparator1"
                        title="Lock away your company files"/>
                    <button 
                        description="Place your workbook in the Corporate Locker. Information may be accessed by others"
                        id="Button2"
                        imageMso="ReviewProtectWorkbook"
                        label="Corporate Locker"/>
                    <button 
                        description="Place your workbook in a Group Locker. Only members of your Group can access it."
                        id="Button3"
                        imageMso="SheetProtect"
                        label="Group Locker"/>
                    <button 
                        description="Place your workbook in a Locker that can only be accessed by users you have invited."
                        id="Button4"
                        imageMso="ProtectDocument"
                        label="Invite Locker"/>
                    <button 
                        description="Place workbook in a Private Locker that can only be accessed by you."
                        id="Button5"
                        imageMso="Lock"
                        label="Private Locker"/>
                </menu >
            </splitButton >
        </officeMenu >
    </ribbon >
</customUI >
```

Comment: The order of the components seemed to be causing the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can rearrange and change toolbar buttons, menus, and menu commands by using the mouse or you can use the Rearrange Commands dialog box, which you can access by using the keyboard. Tasks that you can accomplish by using the keyboard are identified as (keyboard accessible). [Check this out to find more](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-button-menu-or-command-to-a-toolbar-or-menu-0a190d5c-7628-424a-a0cb-da01ddafa3ac?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: This does let me add a new button. But not a button I can specify in my code as far as I'm concerned?

Comment: you also can use macros for custom menu items